# AttributeError: object has no attribute '_state'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm working on this django app, and I've been getting this AttributeError.

Here is my **models.py**:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    provider = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="service_provider", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User_s = get_user_model()


class ProfileServices(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):

    template_name = 'users/manage_listed.html'
    queryset = User_s.service_provider
    context_object_name = 'service_list'
```

And in the html template it's being called as follows:

```
{% for services in service_list.all %}
```

The error I get is *'ProfileServices' object has no attribute '_state'*

Any help would be highly appreciated! 
Thanks!

**Edit Whole error message with Full Traceback:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/3/owned/

Django Version: 2.0.2
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'bootstrap4',
 'users',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'flats',
 'haystack',
 'bugreport',
 'django_messages',
 'services',
 'subscriptions']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\yk\onyx-main\My_site\mysite\templates\base.html, error at line 0
   'ProfileServices' object has no attribute '_state'
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : {% load staticfiles %}
   3 : <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   4 :   <head>
   5 :     <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
   6 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
   7 :     <!-- FONT AWESOME ICONS -->
   8 :     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   9 :     <!-- GOOGLE FONTS -->
   10 :     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in get_queryset
  562.                 return self.instance._prefetched_objects_cache[self.field.related_query_name()]

During handling of the above exception ('ProfileServices' object has no attribute '_prefetched_objects_cache'), another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  175.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  155.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\test\utils.py" in instrumented_test_render
  98.     return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  67.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  943.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  910.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  161.                 values = self.sequence.resolve(context, True)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  676.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in resolve
  802.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  864.                             current = current()

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in all
  155.         return self.get_queryset()

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in get_queryset
  565.                 return self._apply_rel_filters(queryset)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py" in _apply_rel_filters
  541.             db = self._db or router.db_for_read(self.model, instance=self.instance)

File "C:\Users\yk\Anaconda3\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in _route_db
  262.             if instance is not None and instance._state.db:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /users/3/owned/
Exception Value: 'ProfileServices' object has no attribute '_state'
```

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a little more detail for your view? It looks to me like you aren't using ListView's correctly, here is the documentation, scroll down to see the example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Comment: Post the whole error message with full traceback please. Also consider fixing your indentation in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it to work!

Here is the **Views.py**:

```
class ProfileServices(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_t = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return user_t.service_provider.all()

    template_name = 'users/manage_listed.html'

    context_object_name = 'service_list'
```

I'm guessing the issue was the **get_user_model()** method which I was using.